# How many times will a cron job run when given asterisk (*) on all positions?

Tags: cron, services, automation, schedule

If we define a cron job with `* * * * * /some/task/to/perform`, how many times will the job be executed in 60 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once every 60 seconds i.e. every minute.

Check `man 5 crontab` to get more idea on this.

Answer (score 2):

Once. It will execute exactly once every 60 seconds (except when there's a leap second added or removed).